# A good way to implement a string tokenizer ( or use one that's already established )

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, tokenize

Found myself in a situation where I was making one of two rookie mistakes:

1. Writing code that I should get out of a library
2. Writing super complex code that could be greatly simplified using better patterning

What I'm trying to do is pretty simple, I need to send instructions to some JavaScript code that prints fields from an object to the page.  Things started out fine, the following string:

```
message, tags, date
```

Easily instructed the code to get these elements from the object using

```
field_array = instruction_string.split(',')

obj['message'], obj['tags'], obj['date']
```

Then I realized that I wanted to modify that date field to reflect the time zone I was in. Enabling the string to carry special instructions for a field added a little complexity with regex, but still wasn't too complicated:

```
message, tags, date(GMT-5)
```

Using the code:

```
var special_instruction = /\(.*\)/ig.exec('date(GMT-5)')[2]
RESULT: special_instruction = 'GMT-5'
```

I realized that I was getting in over my head when I realized that I also wanted to tell the output to adjust the date so that it reflects the time delta since right now instead of printing the actual date:

```
message, tags, date(GMT-5_)(SINCE_NOW)
```

The regex that I wrote didn't work:

```
var special_instruction =  /\((.*)\)/ig.exec('last_updated(GMT-5)(since_now)')
RESULT: special_instruction = 'GMT-5)(since_now'
```

Although there is probably a way to fix the regex, this indicates that I should be using a tool or established pattern to do this instead of writing custom code off the cusp and screwing around with it for way too long.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to use strings and regular expressions for this?

An alternative would be to use an array and objects for defining the fields that should be printed.

Something like this:

```
var fields = [{
   name: 'message'
}, {
   name: 'tags'
}, {
   name: 'date',
   timezone: 'GMT-5',
   since: new Date() // now
}];
```

For getting the values from that sure be printed you can iterate over the array and look for the `name` field. If you found an object with name `date` you can look for additional properties. You could also add new properties very easily.

Comment: The problem is that the information needs to come from a string. Eventually, it can be in an object like that, but it needs to start out as a string.

Comment: If the string is JSON, it can be trivially converted to such an object.